# what is the reason behind this weird behavior of @html.actionlink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

in my razor syntax

```
@foreach(var item in List<user>TempData["lst"])
{
    <td>@item.something</td>
    <td>@item.something2</td>
    if(somecondition)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Link text","ActionName","Controller Name",new {@item.something3,@item.something4})
    }
}
```

In the Controller I have this

```
public ActionResult  ActionName(string something3, string something4)
{
}
```

now if i mention the controller name in the `@Html.ActionLink()` then the values of `something3` and `something 4` are sent as `null`.
But if i do not add the controller name in the `@Html.ActionLink()` then it sends the correct values in the item to the controller. Can someone explain me this.

Comment: Because your using the wrong overload - it needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("Link text","ActionName","ControllerName",new { item.something3,item.something4 }, null)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell the link what variables to insert your data from your view  into.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Link text","ActionName","Controller Name",new {something3 = @item.something3, something4 = @item.something4})
```

That will allow your controller to pick up what data your sending into your method parameters.

Hope this helps.